# the key of the array of drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

```
    /**
 * @param (string) $key
   */
     function _mycaptcha_get_ask($key = NULL) {

  $ask = array(
'Where does a pilot work?' => 'airplane',
'What day is before Saturday' => 'Friday',
'Which letter is the different between here and there' => 't',
 );

  return isset($key) ? $ask[$key] : $ask;
  }


/**
* @param (array) $form
*/
function mycaptcha_ask_form(&$form) {
  $ask = _mycaptcha_get_ask();
 if (isset($_SESSION['mycaptcha_ask_key']) && $ask[$_SESSION['mycaptcha_ask_key']]) {
   $ask_key = $_SESSION['mycaptcha_ask_key'];
  }

  if (!$ask_key) {
   $_SESSION['mycaptcha_ask_key'] = $ask_key = array_rand($ask);
 }

 $form['mycaptcha_ask'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#required' => 1,
'#title' =>$ask_key,
'#weight' => -1,
  );
}
```

The code is written from someone else, and I cannot understand it very well, especially the $_SESSION['mycaptcha_ask_key'] variable. I don't know from where the key 'mycaptcha_ask_key' from.

Answer (score 1):

The $_SESSION variable is used for interacting with data stored for a individual users session. It works in a similar way to the $_POST and $_GET variables.

Take a look at http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: i am sorry,i still don't understand why the $_SESSION['mycaptcha_ask_key'] array key is mycaptcha_ask_key,could i use another name of it. eg:ask_key.

Comment: The reason is security, because $_SESSION['mycaptcha_ask_key'] is kept on the server it prevents malicious individuals from tricking the script into letting them give the same answer over and over again.

Comment: now, i have konw a little about the $_SESSION[] array. but how should i to name it's key?on the above code. the key is mycaptcha_ask_key'.could i name it in other ways?

Comment: yes, you can name variables in whatever way makes sense to you

Comment: However, remember that your module is just one of possibly many which are running on that site. So it is important to tay inside the namespace (name) of your module for functions, global variables, session variables and so on.